# Pages/folder can't be accessed after publishing in IIS

Tags: c#, iis, .net-core

I'm trying to develop web application using .NET Core 3.0.

Assuming my folder structure like this:

**Project_Root**
   - wwwroot 
  -  Background 
  - Data 
  - Models 
  - Pages 
        > Shared 
        > Module1
        > Module2

While I'm develop and executing this web using visual studio debug function, everything is fine. I can access my module from index page and able to do cross module.

However, after I publish this setup, my link to module1 return page can't be found. I believe, my other folder like Background also inaccessible.

What's really the problem?

Comment: IIS the clients to not have access to the resources on the server like folder and files.  Clients have only GUEST privileges on the server.  Any resource the clients use should be placed on the client machine or on a Network folder where client have access.

Comment: I believe when we publish .net core web, all the details (folder,etc) will be 'embedded' into the dll if I'm not mistaken. Based on my reading I may need to add routing in my startup.cs. 
That's the problem, when I tried to add routing for the folder inside the Pages folder, it seems doe not recognize it as  subfolder and all my files inside it seems inaccessible. 
Am I developing the structure wrong? In my opinion, it's up to the developer to design and create folder for their source code wherever they like. I think that's the reason I choose to develop using .net core at the first place.

Comment: It is a security issue.  You could run the service as a admin but then you are allowing guests to access the server file system.  With a Net application any files needed by the application need to be in same folder as the executable unless a path is specified.  So you could put files on a network drive that users have access.  You could have users put the files on the client and then using environmental variables determine where the files are located.